# Need help getting my web site to publish info to Facebook wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, message

SO I am trying to have my web site publish info to a user's facebook page. Where I am now is that I placed the following code (as instructed by another stackoverflow contributor), which is getting executed however the alert with "error occurred" comes up. Do I need to request the publish_stream permission as well? If so, I cannot figure out how to add that to my code. Sorry, I'm not much of a scripter and I have very limited knowledge on doing any integration into facebook. My ultimate goal is to be able to post information to a users facebook page on their behalf (this won't be done without their permission). Any help would be much appreciated:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
      oauth    : true
});
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
   var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
   FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
     if (!response || response.error) {
       alert('Error occured');
     } else {
       alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
     }
})
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I don't see anything specific to Lotus Domino in your question or in your code. Is there a reason why you call it out in the subject line and with a tag?

Comment: Just in case there are any developers out there that might know of issues interfacing Domino apps with Facebook. I'll edit the title, which hopefully will get me more responses. Thanks!

Comment: Can you help with this, rhsatrhs

Comment: I'm afraid not.  I've never worked with the FB API.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you expand the error handling a little bit?

```
   alert("Error occured: " + response.error.message);
```

And did you check the console log  for errors? Maybe authentication didn't work.